# How to add an event within a calendar

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad, ios5, xcode4.2

I'm doing a calendar for iPad where until now
I have the calendar view, however, now I need to create an event inside it.
I Base in this example with YFCalendar http://www.yellowfield.co.uk/blog/?p=28

Now I need to add a new event which can be added by the time the current day

however, I want to see the summary of the event in a small window similar to the default calendar.

Example_Image:
http://media.wiley.com/Lux/45/271245.image1.jpg

I don't know what kind of control I need to achieve this result.

I do not use default calendar

some recommendations?
preferably something with open source to analyze, in any way, any answer is welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the event kit programming guide located here:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/EventKitProgGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html

Here's apple sample code: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/SimpleEKDemo/Introduction/Intro.html

The code for adding an event uses the EKEventEditViewController:

```
// Create an instance of EKEventEditViewController 
EKEventEditViewController *addController = [[EKEventEditViewController alloc] init];

// Set addController's event store to the current event store
addController.eventStore = self.eventStore;
addController.editViewDelegate = self;
[self presentViewController:addController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

After adding, you can fetch events using code from that tutorial which retrieves events with a predicate (in this case date):

```
NSDate *startDate = [NSDate date];

//Create the end date components
NSDateComponents *tomorrowDateComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
tomorrowDateComponents.day = 1;

NSDate *endDate = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateByAddingComponents:tomorrowDateComponents
                                                                toDate:startDate
                                                               options:0];
// We will only search the default calendar for our events
NSArray *calendarArray = [NSArray arrayWithObject:self.defaultCalendar];

// Create the predicate
NSPredicate *predicate = [self.eventStore predicateForEventsWithStartDate:startDate
                                                                  endDate:endDate
                                                                calendars:calendarArray];

// Fetch all events that match the predicate
NSMutableArray *events = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[self.eventStore eventsMatchingPredicate:predicate]];

return events;
```

Comment: Let me check it, it will serve me well for my personal calendar which will be receiving and sending data to a web platform using JSON?
  I do not use local calendar

Thanks

Comment: I watched video and it's useful but i don't use default calendar, so, i don't know if I need to other kind of things because I am using  JSON to add events in a web platform

Comment: Can you clarify your question - are you using a web view in a phone app?  Are you sending json data to a server and then maintaining a server clendar - a bit confused ...

Comment: Of course! I had to make a personal calendar (it is not default calendar) where I am using JSON to receiving and sending dates from a  web platform. So, When I add an event to my personal calendar (created by me) add an event inside the cell in the calendar.

So, I need to  know how to create a detail view of the event like this picture http://media.wiley.com/Lux/45/271245.image1.jpg  with the possibility to edit the event.

This detail event I guest is showed in a popover control. I just wanna know how to create this view -->  http://r-force.up.seesaa.net/image/e_101103_0.png

thank you!